# guidelines for production website

Tags: java, spring-mvc, deployment

background: I have been a developer for many years, but never really got involved in administration/deployment of products

Now I am developing (in my free time) a social website in Java using Spring MVC and MySQL, at some point I want it to go live, what are the guide lines/ checklist for  doing so?

for example:

1. **Legal**: how do I make sure business model does not clash with law?
   what about privacy terms of user? on other websites I find things like Registration number, VAT number ??? etc...
2. **SEO and marketing**: How do I let people know about my website?
3. **Hosting**: how? godaddy? Amazon Web services? how I do handle
   staging/production? (or a merge? host on godaddy and keep files/Database on amazon??)
4. **Logging/Monitoring**: what/when/where should I log? should I only log errors
   ? or normal flow as well?
5. **Performance**: How to monitor it? how to identify bottle necks/ lags?
6. **Security**: How do I make sure everything is secure? user data/penetration etc...

what are other aspects I didn't think of ?

I would appreciate it if the answer is specific as possible to the environment I described :)

Comment: Its an off topic question - `Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll begin from the bottom

**Security:** There are a lot many things to keep in mind intending to keep your app secure. Check [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top10#OWASP_Top_10_for_2013). In my opinion if you are using spring-mvc better go with spring security. [Spring security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) is a comprehensive framework which provides end to end security features for your web application. You don't have to write explicit code for encrypting passwords & all.

**Performance:** You can use performance monitoring tools like [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) for monitoring the performance of your app.

**Logging/Monitoring/Hosting:** All these depends on the platform you will host your app on. If you are using a PAAS service like Google App Engine, Heroku or a IAAS like AWS Amazon Web Service. They provide their own APIs & solutions for achieving logging, monitoring etc. You can also set up your own infrastructure buy from godaddy etc. You should do some research on PAAS Platform as a Service, IAAS Infrastructure as a service. The state of the art is hosting on cloud rather than setting up your own infrastructure.

**SEO and marketing:** You can either do it on your own via social media or hire experts for this. You have to add meta tags and all in your front end code for SEO etc.

**Legal** Don't have much info on this. You will go fine as far as you are not plagiarising.